# C - Prevent use of same variable name in block scope

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, scope

I've inherited some code which I'm going to be refactoring that makes extensive use of multiple variables at different scopes having the same name, ie:

```
int test = 456;
int main(void) {
    int test = 0;
    //...

    for (i=0; i<MAX_VAL; i++) {
        int test = 123;
        //...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know that if the same variable name is only used at two relevant levels of scope, [I can access the globally accessible one by declaring `extern int test` within the deeper/lower levels of scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28300252/is-there-a-scope-resolution-operator-in-c-language). With more than two levels though, I'm not sure which `test` variable is being accessed: the global scope variable or the variable at one scope level higher.

I've decided to re-write the code to use different variable names, and in doing so, have uncovered a lot of bugs that have been hard to track in the past. Is there a way to trigger a warning when such behavior is used? I have to compile the code in both Linux via GCC and Windows via Visual Studio 2010. If a portable approach isn't possible, is there a way for each of these compilers to warn about multiple variables at different scopes with the same name? This would let me build the code and have a list of all locations where such behavior is used.

Thank you.

Comment: If a variable shadows another, you cannot access that of the outer scope. Using an `extern` declaration has a different meaning and does not work for local or file-scope objects. (And it's a very dirty hack for global scope). So, I strongly support you refactoring such objects (and the original author should be punished with <insert your most hated software-tool> not less than 3 weeks.

Comment: Are you flexible on Visual Studio version? VS 2015 reports `warning C4459: declaration of 'test' hides global declaration` and `warning C4456: declaration of 'test' hides previous local declaration` accompanied by `note: see declaration of 'test'` referencing previous declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both gcc and clang support the `-Wshadow` flag which warns about variables that shadow one another:

> -Wshadow
>
> Warn whenever a local variable or type declaration shadows another variable, parameter, type, class member (in C++), or instance variable (in Objective-C) or whenever a built-in function is shadowed. Note that in C++, the compiler warns if a local variable shadows an explicit `typedef`, but not if it shadows a `struct`/`class`/`enum`.

From Visual Studio 2015 [you get a warning by default](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/12/improvements-to-warnings-in-the-c-compiler.aspx):

> Shadowed variables
>
> A variable declaration "shadows" another if the enclosing scope already contains a variable with the same name. For example:
>
> ```
> void f(int x)
> {
>   int y;
>   {
>     char x; //C4457
>     char y; //C4456
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The inner declaration of x shadows the parameter of function f, so the compiler will emit:
>
> *warning C4457: declaration of 'x' hides function parameter*
>
> The inner declaration of y shadows the declaration of y in the function scope, so the compiler will emit:
>
> *warning C4456: declaration of 'y' hides previous local declaration*
>
> Note that, as before, a variable declaration with the same name as a function parameter but not enclosed in an inner scope triggers an error instead:
>
> ```
>  void f(int x)
>  {
>    char x; //C2082
>  }
> ```
>
> The compiler emits:
>
> *error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'x'*

For older versions of Visual Studio you could enable [Code Analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419384.aspx) (see [How do I enable the 6000 series warnings (code analysis warnings) in MSVC++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10163942/3235496)) and take a look at warnings [C6244](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35whedce.aspx) and [C6246](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeb7y4c0).

Answer (score 3):

With `gcc` you can use `-Wshadow` option to get a warning when a variable shadowds another variable of the same name. On MSVC there is apparently no similar option (on Visual Studio 2010 but as [manlio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32254231/1119701) added in his answer with Visual Studio 2015 they added a warning by default).